# How to get the phone number?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, phone-number

I'm trying to put in an edittext the phone number that was selected by user. I have a button :-

```
contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });
```

and the function below :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                String phone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.NUMBER));
                phone = phone.replace("-", "");
                Log.v("getting phone number", "Phone Number: " + phone);
                txtPhoneNo.setText(phone);

            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

and I got the phone number of last contact. How can I take the phone number that was selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
{
  Uri contactData = data.getData();
  ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
  Cursor curContact = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);

  if ((curContact != null) && (curContact.moveToFirst()))
  {
    String id = curContact.getString(curContact
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID));

    // check there's a phone number at all
    if (Integer.parseInt(curContact.getString(curContact
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
    {

      // get the phone number
      Cursor curNumbers = cr.query(
          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
          new String[] { id }, null);

      if ((curNumbers != null) && curNumbers.moveToFirst())
      {
        String strNumber = 
          curNumbers.getString(
           curNumbers.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));

        curNumbers.close();
      }
    }
    curContact.close();
  }
```

Comment: I get Force Close and in LogCat I have this message : 05-31 10:26:19.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4036): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'has_phone_number' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code!

```
btn_existing_contacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent_contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                /*contacts.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                contacts.setData(People.CONTENT_URI);*/
                startActivityForResult(intent_contacts, 0);
                //displayContacts();


            }
         });
```

after returning from contacts screen,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data)
{
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
String name,mailid,id;
switch(requestCode)
{
case 0:
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK )
        {
            Uri contactdata  = data.getData();

            Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactdata, null, null, null, null);


            if(cur.moveToFirst())
            {
                id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor emailCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",new String[]{id}, null); 
                emailCur.moveToFirst();
                String email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));


                name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                //mailid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                //mailid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email._ID));
                //Toast.makeText(context_contact, "Name:"+name+"\nmailid:"+email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent_add_invitees = new Intent(<ClassContext>,<ur classname>.class);
                intent_add_invitees.putExtra("invitee_name", name);
                intent_add_invitees.putExtra("invitee_mailid", email);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent_add_invitees);
                finish();

            }
        }

    }



}
}
```

Comment: What class is Send_invitations?